# Serial-Serial Hub

Tags: serialization, serial-port

Is it possible to merge 4 serial devices outputting data on 4 separate lines into a single serial line?

In other words -> I see a million 'Serial-USB' hubs that take 4 DB9 inputs and merge them into a single USB output. Is there the same thing but instead of a single USB output we get a single DB9 output?

Comment: Only if you build it yourself.  The USB device you mention works with any software because the USB protocol will actually keep the four pairs of serial data channels separate; the USB host will still "see" 4 serial ports.

Comment: Ah ok. Makes sense. To make one do you have to have the Tx,Rx wires for each device on separate physical wires?

Comment: Not really, the serial-to-USB adapters/hub packetizes the serial data of each channel, and then the USB host sorts it out into individual devices.  You could do the same with a five-port board, and have host software/driver to sort out the packetized data.  You would also have to consider bandwidth: the sum of the 4 baudrates should be less than the host link's baudrate.  IMO: TME so forget about it.